countable set of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}^{d}$
Is the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ which contain a prescribed vertex and are compact and connected, countable?
Hint: It is clear that it is not countable without the restriction that the subsets contain a prescribed vertex and are connected, but how does the situation change if I introduce this constraint?

Compact and connected in which topology?

There are only countably many finite subsets of a countable set, so yes, even without the prescribed vertex and compactness condition.

And what do you mean by vertex?

If by $\mathbb{Z}^d$ you mean the integer grid in $d$-space then that set is countable. The set of all finite subsets of a countable set is countable. You don't need the restrictions.
